# kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException , when trying to add marker on map after search result in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement google places search autocomplete SDK to my kotlin android application.

Am using the second method listed in the official documentation:

[Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity)

Here is my code :

```
    private  var fromLocation: LatLng? = LatLng(0.0, 0.0)
    private  var toLocation: LatLng? = LatLng(0.0, 0.0)


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val place: Place? = data?.let { Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(it) }
                if (PLACE_PICKING_MODE == 1) {
                    fromLocation = place?.latLng
                    val theIcon = R.drawable.gps_default
                    placeMarkerOnMap(fromLocation, theIcon)
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(fromLocation, 17f))
                } else if (PLACE_PICKING_MODE == 2) {
                    toLocation = place?.latLng
                    val theIcon = R.drawable.gps_default
                    placeMarkerOnMap(toLocation, theIcon)
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(toLocation, 17f))
                }
            } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                val status: Status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data!!)
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                println("user Canceled")
            }
        }


        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                locationUpdateState = true
                startLocationUpdates()
            }
        }


    }
```

everytime, in the end, it ends up with the error `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerExceptio`

**UPDATE**

Based on [JJ Jacobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463412/kotlin-kotlinnullpointerexception-when-trying-to-add-marker-on-map-after-searc/58463824#58463824)  answer, I changed a few lines inside the `IF statements` to be like this:

```
                if (PLACE_PICKING_MODE == 1) {
                    if (place != null) {
                        fromLocation = place.latLng!!
                    }
                    val theIcon = R.drawable.gps_default
                    placeMarkerOnMap(fromLocation, theIcon)
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(fromLocation, 17f))
                } else if (PLACE_PICKING_MODE == 2) {
                    if (place != null) {
                        toLocation = place.latLng!!
                    }
                    val theIcon = R.drawable.gps_default
                    placeMarkerOnMap(toLocation, theIcon)
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(toLocation, 17f))
                }
```

But still it gives me the error:

`Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=4, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.innoventiq.arkbeh/com.innoventiq.arkbeh.MainActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException`

And pointed me to these lines :

`fromLocation = place.latLng!!`

and

`toLocation = place.latLng!!`

Comment: To me, it looks like `latLng` is null, in earlier version, you did not have `place.latLng!!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error code you get, it should pinpoint which line is causing the `NullPointerException`.

If `data = null` (since it's of nullable type Intent?), the `place` will also be `null` (the `data?.let{...}` block only returns `null` in this case). This causes issues in 3 places:

1. In the first `if(PLACE_PICKING_MODE == 1)` block, `fromLocation` will now also be `null` and your call to `placeMarkerOnMap` with a `null` value for the location.
2. In the second `if` block, same problem with `toLocation`
3. When fetching the status from the intent, if `data` is `null`, `data!!` throws a `KotlinNullPointerException`

You probably just need to do some more `null` checks before doing any of the conditional logic.

### EDIT

A good way to do a `null` check would be to do something like the below

```
val place: Place? = data?.let { Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(it) }

if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val place: Place? = data?.let { Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(it) }
        place?.let { //One time null-check for place
            if (PLACE_PICKING_MODE == 1) {
                fromLocation = it.latLng
                val theIcon = R.drawable.gps_default
                placeMarkerOnMap(fromLocation, theIcon)
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.
                    newLatLngZoom(fromLocation, 17f))
            } else if (PLACE_PICKING_MODE == 2) {
                toLocation = it.latLng
                val theIcon = R.drawable.gps_default
                placeMarkerOnMap(toLocation, theIcon)
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.
                    newLatLngZoom(toLocation, 17f))
            }
        }
    } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        val status: Status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data!!)
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        println("user Canceled")
    }
}
```

However, if you look at the documentation you linked in your original question, you can actually get rid of the `data?.let{...}` check because the usual function actually sets data as non-nullable. The function signature

```
override fun onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

actually guarantees that the intent should never be `null`, unless you set it to `null` in your code for your purposes. The real problem should be that `place.latLng` is `null` and probably shouldn't be. But in case that's a possibility in your final app, you need to perform a null-check on that and handle the error.

Comment: I tried it and got another error, please check the updated question.

Comment: Based on that last error, it seems that `place` is not `null`, but `place.latLng` is. (Using the `!!` operator asserts that you expect the value to be not-null, so it throws a `KotlinNullPointException` when it is in fact `null`). I don't know why this would be, but I'm assuming that somehow the intent that the function is receiving somehow isn't formatted in a way that gives you a valid `place.latLng`. It might be a good idea to log the intent and the place right after they're created to see what's going on. I'll also update my answer to help you with null-checking.